# Get user members of nested AD groups and their info

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I have an AD group "Office-Users" in winch different departments user groups are member. Finance-dep holding all users in finance, and Finance-dep are member of Office-Users group and so on.

I like to have all users of the nested groups exported to csv with some more info per user.

I've got all the users out like this:

```
Get-ADGroupMember Office-Users | where{$_.ObjectClass -eq "Group"} | %{Write $_.Name;Get-ADGroupMember $_}
```

But it only returns name, SamAccountName, distinguishedName etc.

I miss the Description, lastLogonTimestamp, whenCreated, Enabled/Disabled for the users, so I can check who is using Office.

Is there a simple way to to this?

I already using this to export all users and their status/info, but it's not based on the Office group. I've tried to modify it, but I failed :)

```
$alist = "Name`tAccountName`tDescription`tLastLogonTimestamp`tCompany`twhenCreated`tAcctEnabled`tGroups`n"
$userlist = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | Select-Object -Property Name,SamAccountName,Description,lastLogonTimestamp,Company,whenCreated,Enabled,MemberOf | Sort-Object -Property Name
$userlist | ForEach-Object {
$grps = $_.MemberOf | Get-ADGroup | ForEach-Object {$_.Name} | Sort-Object
$arec = $_.Name,$_.SamAccountName,$_.Description,[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp).ToString('d MMMM yyyy'),$_.Company,$_.whenCreated,$_.Enabled
$aline = ($arec -join "`t") + "`t" + ($grps -join "`t") + "`n"
$alist += $aline
}
$alist | Out-File C:\temp\ADUsers.csv
```

/Kim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this to work:

```
$alist = "Name`tAccountName`tDescription`tLastLogonTimestamp`tCompany`twhenCreated`tAcctEnabled`n"
$userlist = Get-ADGroupMember Office-Users -Recursive | Get-ADUser -properties * | Select-Object -Property Name,SamAccountName,Description,lastLogonTimestamp,Company,whenCreated,Enabled | Sort-Object -Property Name
$userlist | ForEach-Object {
$arec = $_.Name,$_.SamAccountName,$_.Description,[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp).ToString('HH:mm d MMMM yyyy'),$_.Company,$_.whenCreated,$_.Enabled
$aline = ($arec -join "`t") + "`t" + "`n"
$alist += $aline
}
$alist | Out-File C:\temp\Office-users.csv
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

How about changing that first line to this?

```
Get-ADGroupMember Office-Users | where{$_.ObjectClass -eq "Group"} | %{Write $_.Name;Get-ADUser (Get-ADGroupMember $_) -properties *}
```

Now you have all properties for the users in those groups, and can selectively display whichever properties you care about.

Comment: I get: Get-ADGroupMember : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'properties'.

Comment: @kimr-dk I think that was because closing parenthesis should have been before -properties *, which is really for users. Updated that above, can you check again?

Comment: Yes, that was better, but for every group member of the Office-Users: "Get-ADUser : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser' required by parameter 'Identity'. Specified method is not supported.
"